# Changing field type from Checkbox to Formula(Checkbox)

Tags: formula-field, custom-field, checkbox, data-types

I have read that change in field type would result in data loss.

I have a custom field which is of type checkbox and has around 200 records. Now, I need to change this field data type to formula (Checkbox).

Will I need to upload data again or formula field will recalculate the value for checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Formula fields are special read-only fields that cannot be converted
>   to any other data type. Likewise, you cannot convert any other field
>   type into a formula field.

This is from [salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm&type=5) documentation. So you can not change checkbox to formula field.